# Best way to parse a string to a float with both "," and "." as fraction separator? (For a number < 5)

Tags: .net, parsing, internationalization, floating-point

This is kind of related to [my previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147801/best-way-to-parse-float) question, but not really.
I have an input of which I don't know the culture. So it can both use ',' and '.' as separator for the fraction. The number will never be >5 though, so we can be rather sure if there's a separator, it will be for the fraction.

I was looking at the `TryParse` method. It accepts a `NumberStyles` argument. But I don't see anything about fraction separator or the like..

Am I missing something again or is there a better way to reach my goal?

Comment: Thx for keeping the post updated after the discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
float.TryParse(myString.Replace(',', '.'), out myfloat);
```

**EDIT**: as Jon mentioned, the following way is recommended:

```
float.TryParse(myString.Replace(',', '.'), 
               System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, 
               System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
               out myFloat);
```

Comment: If you explicitly want to use "." as the separator, I'd pass in CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as well.

Comment: This can fail if there are also thousant separators.

Comment: @Gamecat: The question says the number is less than 5.

Comment: Gamecat - that's exactly what I was just thinking!
 I guess you'd have to get to the end of the string and work backwards, treating the first , or . as the decimal separator and ignoring everything you subsequently found.

Comment: @Mehrdad - oops. I skimmed that, too. :-)

Comment: @Gamecat: Sure, but a number with a thousand separators is way too large (or rather, too small) to fit into a float anyhow.

Comment: @Dana, I think you are underestimating float type.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I might be :P Can it actually store a fraction that small? With a thousand separators in it?

Comment: "1,234.5" is a valid float and it has a thousand separator.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Haha, I misread GC! I read him as saying if there were a thousand commas it would fail :P  As in 0.000,000,..[998 more commas]..,001

Comment: @Mehrdat Afshari, I know, but I just added the remark for if somebody else uses the solution without the constraint.

Comment: Mehrdad or someone else with enough points please edit the text to include Jon's hint with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. Thanks.