# How to parse a number like "-2.000000e+000"

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I am trying to read some data from a xml file, numbers are saved in forms like "-2.000000e+000"

I tried to use "double.Parse" but it returns the number as -2000000!!!! can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/convert-from-scientific-notation-string-to-float-in-c?

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/c-parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation

Comment: You might also want to look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147801/best-way-to-parse-float

Comment: Does allowing `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` make any difference ?

Comment: +1 Useful, but in your app's current locale "." in numbers doesn't means a lot, or a fraction delimeter, as it is true in netral (en-US) culture

Comment: Guys my program worked fine on my own PC but when I brought it to university it did this stupid stuff...I think the problem could be number seperator on the windows of university PC?? damn I have 5 minutes to hand in my assignement!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the call to `double.Parse`:

```
double.Parse("-2.000000e+000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```